# Djang-allauth signup issue on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, django-allauth

before I get any deeper I’d just like to ask if any of you have experienced this issue.
When in local environment logging and signing up redirection work fine.
After deploying to Heroku, logging is fine but after signing up, redirection is not working and I’m getting Server Error 500.
Unfortunately, Heroku logs don’t give me any closer description why it is so.
It is just suspicious that locally is everything fine.
Is there any known issue I should be aware of? I haven’t found anything online and already spent days digging.
Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Show the log from heroku, Turn DEBUG to True if it is on False then display the error message.

Comment: Is your app in production running on DEBUG = False or DEBUG = True?